# How to get a dataset returned from a stored procedure in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which returns a dataset

Let's say its name is spx and it returns

```
I'd name
1.   Abc
2.   Def
```

I want to get it's result in a temp table in another stored procedure dynamically like if in future I change the dataset in my above so it will reflect here

Like this

```
exec spx
```

It will execute the SP and I want it's result set in a table

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the temporary table you can use standard SQL

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
(
    ID INT,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC spTest

Select * FROM #TempTable
```

If you don't want to define the table you can use OPENROWSET

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC spTest')

Select * FROM #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT  * INTO [temp-table] FROM OPENQUERY("server-name", 'EXEC spx');
```